# Endpoints can be reached without token, even though AddAuthentication was added

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

though authentication and authorization were configured in the `Program.cs` file in the asp.net core web API app, the front end can still access the endpoints without the need for a token.

here's my code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
          .AddUserSecrets<UserSecretsDto>()
          .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();

builder.Services.AddCors();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<HRContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("HRConnection")));
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you add the `[Authorize]` attribute to your endpoint method or controller class?

Comment: in the past with .net core 3, I didn't have to do that, but I'll give it a shot tho.

Comment: @Yitz after having added `[Authorize]`, the endpoint of one of the controllers couldn't be accessed, even by sending a token in the header.

Comment: Add JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme as AuthenticationSchemes in properties of Authorize attribute

Comment: @Timothy it works, but I still find it annoying to add `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` at the top of every controller, I mean I used to not do that in .net core 3, there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this line to the program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build()));
    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;

});
```

and now my endpoints are protected.